# What is the difference between differnet background colors of questions in StackExchange?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design, stack-exchange

As you can see in the following sample picture some questions have a white background and some a bright cream-ish color. I wanted to know the difference between these two.

[image]

I am also wondering about the color coding of the fonts used for the answers. As you notice on the highlighted section on the left, some have a yellow font and some while in the military green background.